# Cycling Between Mission Control Windows with the Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, mission-control

Is there any way to cycle between Mission Control (<kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>) windows with the keyboard? I'm referring first and foremost to moving between the windows shown in the bird's eye view, see image.

Either native or 3rd-party solutions are most welcomed.

[image: mission control bird's eye view]

Thank you.